# xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Tags: xargs

I'd like to count all the ordinary file on home directory with commands:

```
$ find ~ -type f | xargs echo | wc -w
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

It prompts

```
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

What's the problem with usage?

Comment: Do you really want to count the total number of *words* in all the filenames, or do you actually want to count the number of files? if the latter, then you can avoid processing the names altogether e.g. `find ~ -type f -printf 1 | wc -c` (print a single - arbitrary - character for each file, and count those)

Answer (score 20):

It appears that some of your filenames have apostrophes (single quote) in their names.

Luckily, `find` and `xargs` have ways around this. `find`'s `-print0` option along with `xargs`'s `-0` option produce and consume a list of filenames separated by the `NUL` (`\000`) character. Filenames in Linux may contain ANY character, EXCEPT `NUL` and `/`.

So, what you really want is:

```
 find ~ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty wc -w
```

Read `man find;man xargs`.

Comment: `find ~ -type f | wc -l` will work with more files, since xargs put all arguments on one command line and there is a limit in the number of args.

Comment: @pim  While it may be correct that `xargs` can suffer from argument list too long error, in this answer `-print0` and `xargs -0` combination is perfectly acceptable. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83803/85039

Comment: I think the OP's use of `wc -w` may have led you to suppose they want to count the words *inside* the files - they're actually using `xargs echo | wc -w` which will count the number of words in the file *names*, which I think is more likely an attempt to count the number of files (although it doesn't take into account that filenames may contain whitespace). (Likewise, `find ~ -type f | wc -l` doesn't take into account that filenames may contain newlines.)